# Confide custom validator

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ardent

I am using confide for user authentication. I wanna use custom rules using laravel's Validator (for firstname and lastname) class as in

```
$validator = Validator::make($user, $this->rules[$ruleset]);
```

and check with `$validator->passes()`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First create your custom validation class. Something like this:

```
class CustomValidator 
{
    /** 
     * @return bool 
     */
    public function validateFirstname($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    {
        // Do here your Firstname validation 
        ... 
    }

    /** 
     * @return bool 
     */
    public function validateLastname($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    {
        // Do here your Lastname validation 
        ... 
    }

}
```

Then register the new validation rules. For example at `bootstrap/start.php` file add:

```
Validator::extend('firstname', 'CustomValidator@validateFirstname');
Validator::extend('lastname', 'CustomValidator@validateLastname');
```

Then you can use the new rules `firtsname` and `lastname` in your models.

I hope it works fine for you.