# Laravel with Confide - Custom validator not working?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

The documentation of the [Zizaco/confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) package for [Laravel](http://laravel.com) isn't very descriptive when explaining how to use custom validators. I'd like to be able to validate first name, last name, address, city, state etc. fields in my registration process however I haven't found anything that works besides modifying the vendor package. Per the documentation, I should be able to put this in `app/models/AccountValidator.php`

```
<?php
use Zizaco\Confide\UserValidatorInterface;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUserInterface;

class AccountValidator implements UserValidatorInterface {

    public function validate(ConfideUserInterface $user) {

        unset($user->password_confirmation); // Because this column doesn't really exists.

        Log::info("Using a custom validator!");

        return true;
    }
}
```

and in `app/start/global.php`

```
App::bind('confide.user_validator', 'AccountValidator');
```

I've tried putting my rules in the validate function as well as outside of it with no luck, instead of validating anything it'll try to insert the empty values to the database. I've also tried `composer dump-autoload` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/issues/308#issuecomment-48975632). I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788297/confide-custom-validator) but the only answer doesn't appear to be an "official" solution, and Zizaco has not replied to [this question](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/issues/348#issuecomment-50548752) on Github (yes I did try that code as well), so I'm not sure what else to try.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm...it looks like you're doing it right. Did you add `implements ConfideUserInterface` to your model and add `use ConfideUser` inside of the class declaration?

Comment: Yep, it's always one of the first things I do. It validates the username, email and password fields - none of the extras. I did however notice that there's [two separate rulesets in the vendor package](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/blob/master/src/Confide/UserValidator.php#L44). Should I also be passing that multidimensional array in the custom validator?

Comment: It looks like you do need to pass the `$rules` as a multi-dimensional array. Have a look at line 163 of UserValidator.php. I checked my `UserValidator` and mine is setup as multi-dimensional.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I was only passing the rules at first instead of validating them. I setup the validate function to actually validate the data and all seems to work fine now. The documentation wasn't clear, I had thought you only need to pass the rules to the package and it would take care of the data automatically. Guess not..

Comment: I don't have a `validate` method in my `UserValidator`, only the `$rules` parameter (as a multi-dimensional array), just FYI.

Comment: I figured it out, instead of implementing `UserValidatorInterface` I extended `UserValidator` on my custom validator and it works fine now without the `validate` method. My bad, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Confide\UserValidator as ConfideUserValidator;
use Zizaco\Confide\UserValidatorInterface;

class UserValidator extends ConfideUserValidator implements UserValidatorInterface
{
    public $rules = [
        'create' => [
            'username' => 'required',
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:4',
        ],
        'update' => [
            'username' => 'required',
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:4',
        ]
    ];
}
```